# Can I use sklearn cross_val_score with two different input?

Tags: scikit-learn, keras

My problem is:
'can I use sklearn cross_val_score with two different input?'

I concatenated two LSTM model with each different X and with same target Y.
And I tried to check cross_val_score. but it isn't work.

```
def concat():
input1 = Input(shape=(6,1))
pay = LSTM(10)(input1)
pay = Dense(10, activation='relu')(pay)

# DEMO_data net
input2 = Input(shape=(6,1))
bill = LSTM(10)(input2)
bill = Dense(10, activation='relu')(bill)

merge = concatenate([pay, bill])

hidden1 = Dense(10, activation='relu')(merge)

output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(hidden1)
model = Model(inputs=[input1, input2], outputs=output)

model.summary()

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics='accuracy'])

return model
```

and I tried this

```
dnn = KerasClassifier(build_fn=concat, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, epochs=NB_EPOCH, verbose=VERBOSE)

# Evaluate using 5-fold cross validation
cv_results = cross_val_score(dnn, PAY_data, BILL_data, y, cv=5)
print(cv_results)
print(cv_results.mean(), cv_results.std())
```

but it didn't work with this below error message

[image: image of error message]

is it impossible to use cross_val_score with two different input?

Comment: coeur thank you for your help!

Comment: The positional arguments of [cross_val_score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html#sklearn-model-selection-cross-val-score) are `estimator, X, y` and therefore you have to pass the two input arrays as a list: `cross_val_score(dnn, [PAY_data, BILL_data], y, cv=5)`

Comment: thanks. but 'cross_val_score(dnn, [PAY_data, BILL_data], y, cv=5)' it also didn't work